# Modify a react library

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I have a task from UX designers to create a datepicker that displays multiple months + time.

In our project, we are currently using react-datepicker library to manage our datepickers.

This is the react component used in our project: 
https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/

The react-datepicker supports both multiple months and time.

The library itself puts the time on the right side of the calendar. However, the UX designers want the time to be at the bottom.

Is there a proper way in doing this without messing around the date-picker library itself? I know it is a big no no to mess around with the library itself, but what options do I have?

Is there a way around this?

If not, I might have to renegotiate with the UX designers.

Comment: looks to me like you can put it on the bottom with a little bit of css.

Comment: I just realized the time are inputs fields instead of scrollable/selectable elements. Even harder than before.

Comment: You can fork their library, make some modifications and install it from the forked repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a reusable date range picker component from scratch. I will not be using the react-datepicker at all for this case.

Comment: hi @FNMT8L9IN82 facing the same issue, did you find a solution ?

Comment: I created a whole new date range picker component from scratch.

Comment: that's great but i'm wondering how you triggered that datepicker like $(this.ref).datepicker() ?

Comment: It's so easy to create a calendar/datepicker. Unless an existing library does exactly what you need, you're better off creating a new one from scratch that's gonna be lite and do exactly what you need.